# Force users to use the WWW domain with Redirected parameters

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to redirect this:

`example.com/product-name-p12.html` (it's product_page.php?id=12 rewrited)

to:

```
www.example.com/product-name-p12.html
```

If I'm using this Rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)-p(.*).html$ product_page.php?id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

it's redirecting to www.example.com/product_page.php?id=12, not to the html version.

Thanks a lot,

Comment: Of course it does: First you rewrite from the html version to the php version with the query string. Then follows the www - redirect. Since you rewritten before html to php - it stays there. If you just want to redirect from example.com/product-name-p12.html to wwww.example.com/product-name-p12.html, just remove the first RewriteRule. Otherwise you would redirect from html to php and then back to html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reverse the ordering of your rule and use `QSA` flag. `QSA` (Query String Append) flag preserves existing query parameters while adding a new one.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteRule ^(.*)-p(.*)\.html$ product_page.php?id=$2 [L,QSA]
```